# Javascript/Phonegap-must call function three times before it executes, then it executes three times

Tags: javascript, function, cordova

I am attempting to test the File API in Phonegap ([this one](https://github.com/siegfriedbolz/cordova-plugin-file/tree/8deec04db6264c2c318caddeadab0b94ade2979c)) with the following code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PhoneGap File test</title>

    <script src="phonegap.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    function onDeviceReady() {
      alert("devceReady");
      window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
         successCallback, error);
    }

    function successCallback(fileSystem) {
      alert("successCallback");
      console.log(fileSystem.root);
      fileSystem.root.getDirectory("turdBurgle",
        {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccess,
        onGetDirectoryFail);
    }

    function error() {
      alert('error function fired');
    }

    function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) {
      console.log("Created dir "+dir.name);
    }

    function onGetDirectoryFail(error) {
     console.log("Error creating directory "+error.code);
     }
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


    </script>

    </head>
  <body>

    <script src="http://192.168.1.200:8080/target/target-script-min.js#anonymous"></script>
  </body>
```

At first I thought nothing at all was happening-there was nothing in the console to indicate that `onDeviceReady` had fired. However, after I added a button to body and gave the `onClick` instructions to fire `onDeviceReady` I saw that after three button clicks `onDeviceReady` DID fire... but it fired three times. Other than this everything performs as you would expect... the directory gets created in the proper place, no errors.

I have tried adding an `onLoad` listener to ensure that the DOM loads before deviceready attempts to execute `successCallback` but the symptoms remain the same.

Comment: Show more code clearly.

Comment: Gladly. Unfortunately there is not a whole lot more code to show as this is just supposed to be an API test. I have edited the post to show the current code in its entirety. The alerts are just there to show me on the screen what is happening without my having to look at the console, but the symptoms remain unchanged. The script src at the bottom of the body is the script needed to run a local version of weinre for debug.